# Changing width of column in Explorer details view with keyboard

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, accessibility

On Windows XP, open up an Explorer window, for example by pressing <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>. Make sure you're in the "details" mode, where you see for each file its size, type, etc.

[image]

As you know, you can use the mouse to change the width of each column by dragging. You can make any column wider or narrower. My question is: How can you do the same thing using the keyboard?

Note: I'm not interested in emulating the mouse using the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-+ (the plus key on the numpad, not the one beside backspace)

That autosizes all the columns. As far as I know, there's no way to adjust them individually.